# struts2 validation framework just print error message to console, not redirecting to input jsp

Tags: validation, struts2

I am using struts2 validation framework, I just want to validate test() method in TestAction class, here are my code and configuration:

```
@Namespace(value = "/")
@Result(name="input", location="test_input.jsp")
public class TestAction
{
private String  name;

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

@Action(value = "test", results = { @Result(name = "success", location = "test.jsp")})
public String test() throws Exception
{
    return "success";
}

@Action(value = "show", results = { @Result(name = "success", location = "test_input.jsp")})
public String show() throws Exception
{
    return "success";
}
}
```

test_input.jsp:

```
 <body>
<s:fielderror></s:fielderror>
<s:form action="test.do" theme="xhtml">
    <s:textfield name="name" label="name"></s:textfield>
    <s:submit value="submit"></s:submit>
</s:form>
</body>
```

test.jsp:

```
<body>
success
<s:debug></s:debug>
</body>
```

TestAction-test-validation.xml:

```
<validators>
<field name="name">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>name is required.</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
</validators>
```

TestAction.class and TestAction-test-validation.xml are in the same package.

struts.xml:

```
<struts>

<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true" />

<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do" />
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/" />


<include file="struts-default.xml"></include>

<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
    <global-results>
        <result name="error">error.jsp</result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception"
            result="error" />
    </global-exception-mappings>

</package>
</struts>
```

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I begin to visit show.do by browser, an input and button appears, I don't type anything in input, just directly click the button, the pages goes to test.do and show 'success' in the page, and I look at the 'debug' content, no any error message in it.
but the strange thing is that: 
 [ERROR] Validation error for name:name is required. 
the above message is printed in eclipse console (I start tomcat in eclipse)
the error message means TestAction-test-validation.xml must be executed by struts2, but why it doesn't redirect to test_input.jsp? I already define an input result.

Is there something wrong in my configuration or I lack other configuration ?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you remove the "simple" theme constant from your S2 config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try extending `ActionSupport` from your Action.

```
public class TestAction extends ActionSupport {
```

It's always a good idea to include it, usually there are no reasons to *not* extends it in every Action of your project.

P.S: this way you can return `SUCCESS` instead of `"success"`,  etc

Comment: ok, it works, but I am still not understood why I must extends ActionSupport.

Comment: @HiwayChe because that is where the validation aware of functionality comes from, if you don't implement it yourself.